# Explain strange Angular's expression behavior

Tags: angularjs

Could someone explain to me why I get **twice** the `alert message` of the following code?

```
<div ng-app="scopeExample" ng-controller="MyController as ctrl"> 
    <input id="box" ng-model="ctrl.num"> {{ctrl.show_num()}}
</div>

<script>
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
.controller('MyController', MyController);

function MyController() {
     this.num=12;
}

MyController.prototype.show_num=function(){
    alert(this.num);
};
</script>
```

Comment: That means your controller is running twice. I'm not sure if your function name being the same as the controller is doing it, or an external factor such as calling the page with a $routeParam method could be casuing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS evaluates all the expressions in a page multiple times, at each digest loop, until the result is stable.

What you're seeing is perfectly normal.

But expressions should not have side-effects like alerting, or modifying values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plunkr - https://run.plnkr.co/wFWMLiO9mqQu2LlU/

It runs twice for you because the event (DOMContentLoaded) is propagated to all the parent elements as well. In this case it only include the `<div>` tag. If you nest this under other tags, it will fire more times.

You should be using the angular $scope instead of prototyping and using the this variable.